# How to check if there is no more rows to fetched using libpq?

Tags: libpq, postgresql-15

I am using C++ and using libpq to access PostgreSQL. I am a newbie to libpq and need to process data of table row by row.
below is snippet of code

```cpp
 PGresult* res = PQexec(conn, "DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR select * from my_table");
   if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK)
   {
     fprintf(stderr, "DECLARE CURSOR failed: %s", PQerrorMessage(conn));
     PQclear(res);
     exit(1);
   }
   PQclear(res);
   while (true) // need a break condition till data is in cursor
  {
     res = PQexec(conn, "FETCH NEXT in myCursor");
     if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK)
    {
      //error handling code and break
    }
     if(PQntuples(res) ==0)
        break;
    //handle the query result
   }
```

Is there a way to check that we have fetched all records and there is no more record left to fetch.
Currently I am relying upon

> PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK  and PQntuples(res) == 0

Comment: Why do you use a cursor?

Comment: Fetch is useful when there is a huge no of rows in db.

Answer (score 0):

when PQntuples(res) is 0 or lesser than the number of rows you try to fetch it means no more data to be fetched.